# converting str to dict python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

```
test_string = '{"Nikhil":{"Akshat" : ["a":2, "fs":1]}}'
```

Want to convert to `dict = {"Nikhil":{"Akshat" : ["a":2, "fs":1]}}`

Found this post:
[Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

But won't work using ast or json.loads(test_string). It seems that it's the list `["a":2, "fs":1]` cause problems. Could someone please provide suggestions on it?

### Thank you.

corrected, should be this `test_string = '{"Nikhil":{"Akshat" : [{"a":2, "fs":1}]}}'`

Comment: Yeah, that’s neither a list nor a dict. Where’d that nonsense come from?

Comment: `["a":2, "fs":1]` is not valid json, and therefore cannot be converted to json

Comment: @Danielle \*cannot be *parsed as* JSON.

Comment: @deceze I wanted to say "unmarshalled" but thought better of it :)

Comment: `dict = {"Nikhil":{"Akshat" : ["a":2, "fs":1]}}` is not valid Python source code. So your expected output dictionary doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input string isn't valid json, so can't be *parsed as* json. If you fix the string, it should work:

```
import json

good_test_string = '{"Nikhil":{"Akshat" : {"a":2, "fs":1}}}'

output_dict = json.loads(good_test_string)
print(json.dumps(output_dict, indent=2))

{
  "Nikhil": {
    "Akshat": {
      "a": 2,
      "fs": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Update for new `good_test_string` from comment:

```
import json

good_test_string = '{"Nikhil":{"Akshat" : [{"a":2, "fs":1}]}}'

your_dictionary = json.loads(good_test_string)
```

works for me. Do you get an error?

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution. My string is good_test_string = '{"Nikhil":{"Akshat" : [{"a":2, "fs":1}]}}'. Want to convert it to dictonary format, so that I can extract the information.  FYI: I exported data from MongoDB.

Comment: @Learning that string doesn't match what you posted in your original question, but it does work - I updated my answer.